# Interactively get readable(i.e. lng/lat) coordinates from a matplotlib basemap plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm doing matplotlib basemap plots. The current coordinates of the mouse pointer are interactively displayed in the lower right area of the figure. But they are in map coordinates (I assume). I would like to have them in lng/lat.

Is there a quick way to do this?
Do I have to dive into mouse events (which I'm not familiar with yet)?

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/image_zcoord.html

Comment: Thanks, tcaswell. That works like a charm. I'll post it as an answer.
Why did I get the downvotes? I didn't know about that format_coord function. I also did a lot of research first, but couldn't find anything. Please someone tell me how this question could be improved, so I can post a better question next time.

Comment: In general it is better to show a _minimal_ amount of code in your question to give some context for what you are asking.  You have have done a lot of research,  but the question does not show it.  This is a bit of tricky case because you have to get the search terms just right to find the magic function.  Don't worry about it too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tcaswell pointed me in the exactly right direction:

```
ax = plt.gca()
def format_coord(x, y):
    return 'x=%.4f, y=%.4f'%(m(x, y, inverse = True))
ax.format_coord = format_coord
```

This does what I wanted.